# Query that shows the total profit in descending order for each month in 2010?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am supposed to write a query that shows the total profit in descending order for each month in 2010.

So far, I have a query that shows the total profits in descending order for 2010 and I have a query that can extract each month, but I can't seem to connect the two.

```
select (SalesPrice - AcquisitionPrice) profit, datesold
from Transaction
where DateSold >= '10-jan-01' and DateSold <= '10-dec-31';
```

and:

```
select to_char(datesold, 'mon')
from transaction
group by to_char(datesold, 'mon')
```

Comment: Has to be mysql.  The second query won't run in Oracle. Also, the date math wouldn't work without a to_date(thingie, format_mask) in Oracle.

Comment: @TGray It will work in Oracle if the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter is set to `YY-MON-DD` as Oracle will try to do an implicit `TO_DATE( datevalue, format_mask )` on string literals using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask. It is better to explicitly specify the format mask (as the client can change session parameters) or to use an ANSI/ISO date literal.

Comment: @MT0, you're right.  I never use that parameter, as a consultant, because there is no commonality across my clients' databases and some of them are working with very old versions (think v6.0.27).  I have found it a good practice to always format dates.  YMMV :)

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT TRUNC( datesold, 'MM' ) AS "Month",
       SUM( SalesPrice - AcquisitionPrice ) AS profit
FROM   Transaction
WHERE  EXTRACT( YEAR FROM datesold ) = 2010
GROUP BY TRUNC( datesold, 'MM' )
ORDER BY TRUNC( datesold, 'MM' ) DESC
```

**MySQL and Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT EXTRACT( MONTH FROM datesold ) AS mnth,
       SUM( SalesPrice - AcquisitionPrice ) AS profit
FROM   Transaction
WHERE  EXTRACT( YEAR FROM datesold ) = 2010
GROUP BY EXTRACT( MONTH FROM datesold )
ORDER BY EXTRACT( MONTH FROM datesold ) DESC
```